# Windows XP can't boot; keyboard doesn't work in the boot menu

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard, boot

I'm facing an error on Windows XP startup.  The keyboard doesn't work and I can't choose *"Start windows normally"*.

After waiting 30 seconds, Windows doesn't start on its own. When I test with a Windows LiveCD, the keyboard works. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Do you get any error on screen?

Answer (score 3):

If a different OS sees the keyboard, it is unlikely to be a hardware problem.  Perhaps something broke in your XP installation.  Try a repair or reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I try to repair OS, restart my PC then enter to CMOS and changed CD-ROM to 1st boot device. I saved the setting and restart my pc again. When press any key to boot from cd.... message appear i can't press any key. If it is OS error, i can boot from CD. It strange for me. Any idea?

Comment: you should associate your accounts to regain ownership of this question, and then edit the question post to add this additional information.  see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon

Comment: wait, are you saying the keyboard *doesn't* work when you try to boot from CD?  that sounds like your keyboard is broken.  try a different keyboard.

Comment: if keyboard is damage, i cant enter to CMOS right?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an USB keybooard, Try Enable USB Keyboard in your Bios.